# how to remove element only if it is dragged outside of container

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='element'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='element'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='element'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='element'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

$('.container').sortable({
stop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.remove(); 
}
});
```

This works but I need to remove `element` only if it is dragged outside of `container` not if it is sorted inside `container`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only define `accept` in `droppable` like this:

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/xtgom9zd/2/)**

**html**

```
<div class="element">Drag me</div>
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
   drop here (container)
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(init);

function init() {
    $('.element').draggable({
        containment: '#content',
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: "invalid",
    });

    $('.container').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'validClass',
        accept: '.element',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var draggedElement = ui.draggable.clone();
            $(event.target).append(draggedElement.html('dragged'));
        }                    
    });
}
```